"Cancelling" the sigma notation from both sides of the equation
I'm trying to work on an exercise given to our class. We need to derive B-6 from B-5 (in the picture) using these properties:
B-5: $ \Psi (\vec r, t_0) = \sum_a C_a \Psi_a(\vec r)$
B-6: $ P_a = \frac{\vert C_a \vert ^2}{\sum_a \vert C_a \vert ^2} $
$$ dP(\vec r, t) = C \vert \Psi (\vec r, t) \vert ^2d^3r \tag{1}$$
$$ \Psi(\vec r, t) = \sum_a C_a \Psi_a (\vec r) \tag{2}$$
$$ \int dP(\vec r, t) = 1 \tag{3}$$
$$ \int dP(\vec r, t) = \int C \vert \Psi(\vec r, t)\vert^2d^3r \tag{4}$$
I've done some solving, and arrived at this (skipping some steps):
$$ C = \frac{1}{\int \Psi(\vec r, t) \Psi^*(\vec r, t) d^3 r} $$
$$ C = \frac{1}{\sum_a \sum_b C_a C_b^* \int \Psi_a(\vec r) \Psi_b^*(\vec r) d^3 r}$$
noting that: $ \int \Psi_a(\vec r) \Psi_b^*(\vec r) d^3 r = \delta_{ab} $
$$ C = \frac{1}{\sum_a \sum_b C_a C_b^* \delta_{ab}}$$
arguing that $a = b$
$$ C = \frac{1}{\sum_a \vert C_a \vert ^2}. \tag{5}$$
Inserting (5) into (1):
$$ \int dP(\vec r, t) = \int \frac{1}{\sum_a \vert C_a \vert ^2} \vert \Psi(\vec r, t) \vert ^2 d^3 r $$
$$ \sum_a P_a = \frac{1}{\sum_a \vert C_a \vert ^2} \int \vert \Psi(\vec r, t) \vert ^2 d^3 r $$
using a similar process used in getting (5)
$$ \sum_a P_a = \frac{1}{\sum_a \vert C_a \vert ^2} \left (\sum_d \sum_e C_d C_e^* \delta_{de} \right )$$
arguing that $ d = e $
$$ \sum_a P_a = \frac{\sum_d \vert C_d \vert ^2}{\sum_a \vert C_a \vert ^2}$$
I'm currently stumped on how to proceed on getting B-6. I think I'm a few steps into getting it, but I do not know how to proceed. Any help is appreciated. Cheers!
Chapter Exercise

From the last  equation you can group terms with the same index:
$$\sum_a \mathscr P_a=\dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_a\,|c_a|^2}{\displaystyle\sum_a\,|c_a|^2}\implies \sum_a\left\{\mathscr P_a-\dfrac{|c_a|^2}{\displaystyle\sum_a\,|c_a|^2}\right\}=0\implies \mathscr P_a=\dfrac{|c_a|^2}{\displaystyle\sum_a\,|c_a|^2}$$

This did not occur to me at all! I realized early on that I can argue that d = a, but that would cancel things out.  Thank you!

For the mathematically challenged (like myself), I was able to expand @Conreu's answer. I'm posting this so that it will be clearer for people who are newer to this. Starting from:
$$ \sum_a P_a = \frac{\sum_a \vert C_a \vert ^2}{\sum_a \vert C_a \vert ^2} = 1$$
(refer to $(3)$ on why the equation above is equal to 1)
$$ \frac{\sum_a \vert C_a \vert ^2}{\sum_a \vert C_a \vert ^2} - \sum_a P_a = 1 - \sum_a P_a $$
since $ \sum_a P_a = 1 $:
$$ \frac{\sum_a \vert C_a \vert ^2}{\sum_a \vert C_a \vert ^2} - \sum_a P_a = 1 - \sum_a P_a = 1 - 1 = 0 $$
$$ \sum_a \left \{ \frac{ \vert C_a \vert ^2}{\sum_a \vert C_a \vert ^2} - P_a \right \} = 0 $$
The above equation is in the form $ \sum_{i=1}^n c = nc $, where $nc = 0$. $n$, therefore, doesn't matter since any value multiplied to zero will be zero. Due to this, we can assume that the expression inside the $\{\}$ are equal to c. We can therefore proceed with:
$$ c = \frac{ \vert C_a \vert ^2}{\sum_a \vert C_a \vert ^2} - P_a = 0 $$
$$ \frac{ \vert C_a \vert ^2}{\sum_a \vert C_a \vert ^2} = P_a $$
$$ P_a = \frac{ \vert C_a \vert ^2}{\sum_a \vert C_a \vert ^2}$$
Once again, thanks to @Conreu for the initial idea.
I don't know how correct the following are, but they are some intermediate steps that I discussed with my classmates:
$$ \sum_a P_a = \frac{\sum_a \vert C_a \vert ^2}{\sum_a \vert C_a \vert ^2} = 1$$
$$ \sum_a P_a - \frac{\sum_a \vert C_a \vert ^2}{\sum_a \vert C_a \vert ^2} = 0$$
$$ \sum_a P_a - \sum_a \sum_a \left \{ \vert C_a \vert ^2 \frac{1}{\vert C_a \vert ^2} \right \} = 0$$
$$ \sum_a \left [ P_a - \sum_a \left \{ \vert C_a \vert ^2 \frac{1}{\vert C_a \vert ^2} \right \} \right ] = 0$$
since the second $\sum_a$ belongs to the second term:
$$ \sum_a \left [ P_a - \vert C_a \vert ^2 \frac{1}{\sum_a \vert C_a \vert ^2} \right ] = 0$$
